# Bootstrap accordion with additional html containers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm trying to make bootstrap accordion. Accordion means when you open one item the current item which is opened needs to be closed.

It works if I add it manually without any additional div or other html containers such as `<article>` that you will see in my example.

My question is it possible to get accordion to work on a simply way. Did I miss something?

```
<div class="panel-group uk-row-first" id="accordion-neuweltenbreucken">
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
        <article class="uk-article" id="accordion" data-permalink="http://neu.weltenbruecken.com/16-accordeon/34-wilkommen">
            <div>

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading main">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapse1" class="panel-toggle collapsed" data-parent="#accordion-neuweltenbreucken"  data-body-background="background1.jpg" data-toggle="collapse"> Willkommen </a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-body collapse">
                        <div class="panel-inner main">
                            <p class="uk-article-lead"><span>Heilung bedeutet, sich an alles zu erinnern, was wir im Bezug auf Verbundenheit und Einheit und gegenseitige Abhängigkeit zwischen allen Dingen, lebendigen und nicht lebendigen, vergessen haben.</span></p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="uk-article" id="accordion" data-permalink="http://neu.weltenbruecken.com/16-accordeon/36-heilbehandlung-fur-mensch-und-tier">
            <div>

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading main">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapse2" class="panel-toggle collapsed" data-parent="#accordion-neuweltenbreucken"  data-body-background="background2.jpg" data-toggle="collapse"> Heilbehandlung für Mensch und Tier </a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-body collapse">
                        <div class="panel-inner main">
                            <!-- Here we insert another nested accordion -->
                            <div id="accordion4" class="panel-group">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapse2Inner1" class="panel-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4"> Schamanische Arbeiten für Menschen </a></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapse2Inner1" class="panel-body collapse">
                                        <p>Vorbereitungsarbeiten Fr. 75 / h , Heilarbeiten Fr. 135 / h, Nacharbeit, Dokumentation Fr. 75 / h</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapse2Inner2" class="panel-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4"> Schamanische und telepathische Arbeit für Tiere </a></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapse2Inner2" class="panel-body collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-inner">
                                            <h5>Telepathische Kommunikation</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Inner accordion ends here -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hajdarevic89/L8jd6f27/)

Comment: Is see the fiddle, but i dont understnad what is the problem, all is working ok?

Comment: @MiomirDancevic No it doesnt work. Opening one needs to close previous opened. That is accordion: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp Scroll down and see "Accordion" title on that page.

Comment: Why do you have accordian inside accordian?  Is that what you need?

Comment: Exactly. That is what I need. Only thing that doesn't work is here "accordion" style is that opening a new item closes previous opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working like an accordion because there are too many levels of nesting below the parent. You need to change it to something like this..

```
<div class="panel-group uk-row-first">
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1 accordion" id="accordion-neuweltenbreucken">
        <article class="uk-article panel panel-default" id="accordion1" data-permalink="http://neu.weltenbruecken.com/16-accordeon/34-wilkommen">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a href="#collapse1" class="panel-toggle panel-title" data-parent="#accordion-neuweltenbreucken" data-body-background="background1.jpg" data-toggle="collapse"> Willkommen </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-body collapse">
                <div class="panel-inner main">
                    <p class="uk-article-lead"><span>Heilung bedeutet, sich an alles zu erinnern, was wir im Bezug auf Verbundenheit und Einheit und gegenseitige Abhängigkeit zwischen allen Dingen, lebendigen und nicht lebendigen, vergessen haben.</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="uk-article panel panel-default" id="accordion" data-permalink="http://neu.weltenbruecken.com/16-accordeon/36-heilbehandlung-fur-mensch-und-tier">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a href="#collapse2" class="panel-toggle" data-parent="#accordion-neuweltenbreucken" data-body-background="background2.jpg" data-toggle="collapse"> Heilbehandlung für Mensch und Tier </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="panel-body collapse">
                <div class="panel-inner main">
                    <!-- Here we insert another nested accordion -->
                    <div id="accordion4" class="panel-group">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapse2Inner1" class="panel-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4"> Schamanische Arbeiten für Menschen </a></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse2Inner1" class="panel-body collapse">
                                <p>Vorbereitungsarbeiten Fr. 75 / h , Heilarbeiten Fr. 135 / h, Nacharbeit, Dokumentation Fr. 75 / h</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapse2Inner2" class="panel-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4"> Schamanische und telepathische Arbeit für Tiere </a></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse2Inner2" class="panel-body collapse">
                            <div class="panel-inner">
                                <h5>Telepathische Kommunikation</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Inner accordion ends here -->
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/MBuBndwI1D